# Can't use Fullscreen option on Google Drive

Tags: browser, google-drive-api, video-streaming, google-drive-shared-drive

for some reason I can't use Fullscreen option on embeded videos on my website. It says that browser doesnt support fullscreen option on mobile phone. Fullscreen does work on desktop but not on mobile phones neither Iphones nor Androids.

I tried using allowfullscreen="true" and similiar codes but its not working.